# Unable to select FLOAT precision when adding column

Tags: qgis, sqlite, precision

I'm trying to do the lessons in the training-manual at qgis.org.

I,m having some problems with  3.3 Ratio Classification http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html

according to the training-manual its supposed to look like this[image: image1]

but mine look like this [image: image 2]

I am unable to select precision and width of FLOAT.

I'm using QGIS 2.2 Valmiera on an iMac.

Please exude my bad english.

Comment: Which kind of table / dataset are you trying to update? SHP or ?

Comment: The dataset was included in the exercise-data that I downloaded from qgis.org, looks like its named landuse.sqlite. http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/training_manual/foreword/preparing_data.html

Comment: Then it is for the reason Andre mentions below. Width/precision only applies to DBF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the same picture, but there is nothing wrong with that.

Spatialite stores REAL values as floating point, hence no precision is needed.
The width and precision fields are necessary for shapefiles, which store REAL data in a database of an old dbase format which needs width and precision to be set explicitely.

It seems that the pictures in the exercise manual are not up to date.